# Converting COLLADA to POD

Tags: collada

Does anybody know what this error mean and how to fix it?
"No supported geometry data found for mesh "SketchUp"
I encountered this when using tool Collada2POD.

I read that article.
Can anybody tell me what the "lines" refer to in the sentence below.

```
    "I ran into that problem, turns out the collada2Pod converter only supports meshes, but sketchUp can generate lines as well as meshes. I had to write my own converter using the OSS Assimp lib."

    "i solved this problem btw, i had a single line which wasn't connected to anything inside my model. Just remove lonely lines and then you should be good to go."
```

Comment: Have you tried to google for the solution? E.g. there is some information: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14230